# Java - What is the order of initialization in this code?

Tags: java, oop

In the following Java code, the Insect class is inherited by the Beetle class.

```
class Insect {

    private int i = 9;
    protected int j;

    Insect() {
        System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
        j = 39;
    }
    private static int x1
            = printInit("static Insect.x1 initialized");

    static int printInit(String s) {

        System.out.println(s);
        return 47;
    }
}

public class Beetle extends Insect {

    private int k = printInit("Beetle.k initialized");

    public Beetle() {
        System.out.println("k = " + k);
        System.out.println("j = " + j);
    }
    private static int x2
            = printInit("static Beetle.x2 initialized");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Beetle constructor");
        Beetle b = new Beetle();
    }
}
```

The output is somehow comfusing.

> static Insect.x1 initialized
>
> static Beetle.x2 initialized
>
> Beetle constructor
>
> i = 9, j = 0
>
> Beetle.k initialized
>
> k = 47 j = 39

**What is the order of initialization in this particular example?**

Why is x2 initialized immediatly after x1? And why is the first line of the main method (`System.out.println("Beetle constructor");`), executed **after** x1 and x2 intializaton. So comfusing.

I know that the derived class constructor automatically calls the base class constructor (unless it has parameters and you'd use the super keyword). I know that variables are initialized before the constructor, and that static variables are initialized before other variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x1` and `x2` are static. This means that they are initialized when the class is loaded. Since the main method is in `Beetle`, the class has to be loaded before invoking `main`. This is why `x1` and `x2` initialization is the first thing you see. Not sure about why the order of those two is as it is.

Now you are calling `main` and `System.out.println("Beetle constructor");` is executed. Then it calls `Beetle()` which implicitly calls `super()` (aka `Insect()`) first. This prints `i = 9, j = 0` because `i` is 9 and `j` has not been initialized at that point, which means it has the default int value 0.

Now `j` is set to 39 and the flow continues in `Beetle()`. This now initializes the fields of `Beetle`, in your case `k`. So when it comes to the explicit code in `Beetle()`, `k` is initialized to 47 and `j` to 39 by the super constructor.

Comment: So I could say, as a general rule, that: 

1. Static members in the base class are initialized first, 
2. Static members in the derived class are initialized next, 
3. Base class non-static members (primitives and references) are initialized 
4. Base class constructor gets called 
5. Derived class non-static members are initialized 
6. Finally I have everything I need to create the object, so the derived class constructor gets called. 

Am I right?

Comment: @HelloLili in this simple case yes but I would be careful with using it as general rule. Java works by a set of rules defined in the Java language specification. I think you are better off with learning how certain actions are triggered. Instead of "static members first" remember "loading a class triggers initialization of it's static members" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This can be explained as follows -

Since static members are non-instance members i.e only one copy of the member is shared across all the instances of the class, these members are initialized first.

In this case, x1 is initialized first since its a static member present in the base class of the class where the main method is present.

Hence, **1st x1 is initialized**.

Static member x2 in the subclass follows because of the same reason and also because there are no other static members present in **Insect class**.

Beetle constructor line is printed from the main method.

The constructors of the super class and sub class are called one after the other for obvious reasons

Answer (score 2):

JVM(Class loader) loads Beetle class, when you invoke its main static method. After class loading, initialization of Beetle class takes place which means initializing all the static members of the class.

The base class is always initialized implicitly, thus you see the x1 initialized before x2.

You see the "Beetle constructor" printed after x1, and x2, because when you reference a static method of a class(as you are doing by calling main), the JVM order of execution jumps to initializing the class static members, before continuing with the execution of the main() method.

As an experiment, try removing the main method to another class,

```
public class Beetle1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Beetle1 constructor");
    }
}
```

Now as the Beetle constructor is not referenced, the class loader does not load it, and you will see Beetle1 constructor printed.